# Массово изменять свойства QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

Имеется Ui-шка с некоторым количество набросанных comboBox на ней. Мне необходимо допустим в коде одновременно у всех поменять какое-либо свойство или подключить коннект. Как это лучше сделать, чтобы избежать дублирование кода? Может есть способ проитерироваться по всем сразу?

Comment: есть, через children()

Comment: Ещё можно воспользоваться механизмом сигналов слотов. У `QComboBox` есть слот `setCurrentIndex(int)`, вы можете подписать у всех ваших QComboBox этот слот на какой-то  ваш сигнал, и эмитить его (сигнал) когда вам нужно поменять текущий элемент в ComboBox-е. И не придётся тогда в цикле обходить все дочерние элементы, производить касты и тому подобное. Вы сэмитили сигнал - у всех комбобоксов, подписанных на этот сигнал изменилось значение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вполне можно итерироватся по дочерним:

```
for (auto child: children()) {
  QComboBox* cb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(child);
  if (!cb)
    continue
  cb->setCurrentIndex(0);
}
```